# error: subprocess-exited-with-error × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build a container image with AWS EC2 Ubuntu to push on AWS ECR Repository for a python script which needs the web3.py library. However, it is throwing me an error that I'm not sure how to fix. I am using AWS ECR push commands to do it.

The command is: `docker build -t docker-lambda` .

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY app.py ./

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
web3
```

Error message:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/var/lang/include/python3.8 -c lru.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/lru.o
      unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Building this lru-dict requires some c packages and libraries.
Install gcc tools:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

along with python-tools for dev:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

try them inside container too....this should work